# Exiting from while loop not working in java

Tags: java

I am new to java programming.I want to calculate the sum and want to exit the program if user enters "N" and again loop if user enters "Y".But,it is not getting me out of loop even I enter "N".

```
public class Program {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a=true;
        while (a) {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
        int d=c.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter a number2");
        Scanner ce=new Scanner(System.in);
        int df=ce.nextInt();

        int kk=d+df;
        System.out.println("total sum is"+kk);

        System.out.println("do you want to continue(y/n)?");
        Scanner zz=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean kkw=zz.hasNext();
        if(kkw) {
           a=true;
        }
        else {
            a=false;
            System.exit(0);
        }
        }
}
```

I didnt know where I made the mistake? Is there any other way?

Comment: `kkw` is always `true`

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm

Comment: You are asking the user to enter y/n, but then ignoring what he says

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- and step through your running code with a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `a` variable is true if `scanner.hasNext()` is true, leading to `a` being `true` with every input, including `"N"` which means, your `while` loop will keep on going until there are no more inputs.

Second of all, you could optimize your code the next way:

1. I suggest getting rid of `a` and `kkw` to make your code cleaner and shorter.
2. Use only one `Scanner` and define it **outside** of the loop. You don't need more than one `Scanner` for the same input. Also, initializing a `Scanner` with every loop is resource-consuming.
3. Use meaningful variable names. Programming should not only be efficient, but also easy to read. In this tiny code it's a minor issue but imagine having an entire program and, instead of adding features and bug-fixing, you had to search for the meaning of every variable.

Here's an optimized and working version of your code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int input1 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine(); // nextInt() doesn't move to the next line

    System.out.println("Enter a second number:");
    int input2 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Total sum is " + (input1 + input2)); /* Important to 
    surround the sum with brackets in order to tell the compiler that 
    input1 + input2 is a calculation and not an appending of
    "Total sum is "*/

    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (Y/N)");
    if (scanner.hasNext() && scanner.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        break;
}
scanner.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I haven't used Scanner for ages. Also, I didn't say it's an error, it's solely a suggestion.

Comment: @user85421 could you please edit my answer regarding the hasNext() issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        System.out.println("enter first number");
        int d = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter second number");
        int df = in.nextInt();
        int kk = d + df;
        System.out.println(String.format("total sum is %d", kk));

        System.out.println("do you want to continue(y/n)?");
        String cont = in.next();
        done = cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n");

    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should absolutely close the Scanner.  Using System.in is the failing, but it doesn't matter since this is throw away code.  Ideally, the program would open a dedicated stream.

Comment: Never leave resources open.  It's programming 101.  It invites memory leaks.  Even if it's something silly like a ByteArrayOutputStream, you should always be in the habit of closing it.

Comment: You should absolutely ***not*** close the Scanner. You should always close every resource you ***open***, but you did *not* open `System.in`, so you should *not* close it.